# How to add case insensitive filtering in react-table for components content?

Tags: reactjs, filter, components, react-table

I have a situation where I'd like to add a link to a `react-table` cell and still be able to filter it. This is what I have now:

```
const columns = [{
            Header: 'Header',
            accessor: 'data',
        }];

        const data = {
            data: <a href="#">Some text</a>,
        };

        return (
            <ReactTable
                columns={columns}
                data={data}
                filterable
            />
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I got it working by using `defaultFilterMethod`:

```
filterCaseInsensitive = (filter, row) => {
    const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
    const content = row[id];
    if (typeof content !== 'undefined') {
        // filter by text in the table or if it's a object, filter by key
        if (typeof content === 'object' && content !== null && content.key) {
            return String(content.key).toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase());
        } else {
            return String(content).toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    return true;
};
render() {
    const columns = [{
        Header: 'Header',
        accessor: 'data',
    }];

    const data = {
        data: <a href="#" key="Some text">Some text</a>,
    };

    return (
        <ReactTable
            columns={columns}
            data={data}
            filterable
            defaultFilterMethod={this.filterCaseInsensitive}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used @Pablo's answer, but since it uses .includes(), I recommend adding a length boundary to the search.

I did so because its an uncomfortable experience to search for things that include, for example, a single letter, which would return lots of matches that the user didn't expect.

```
const fuzzy = (filter, row) => {
    const id = filter.pivotId || filter.id;
    const content = row[id];
    if (typeof content !== 'undefined') {

        if (filter.value.length < 3) {
            // filter by text in the table or if it's a object, filter by key
            if (typeof content === 'object' && content !== null && content.key) {
                return String(content.key).toLowerCase().startsWith(filter.value.toLowerCase());
            } else {
                return String(content).toLowerCase().startsWith(filter.value.toLowerCase());
            }
        } else {
            // filter by text in the table or if it's a object, filter by key
            if (typeof content === 'object' && content !== null && content.key) {
                return String(content.key).toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase());
            } else {
                return String(content).toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase());
            }
        }

    }

    return true;
};
```